# Hashset "value cannot be null" error

Tags: c#, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to execute the follow code and it works fine if myObject is != null but throws a "value cannot be null" error if myObject is null. Ideally, if myObject is null then I'd like to just have the HashSet have a single value of 0.

```
var ids = new HashSet<int>(myObject.Select(p => p.ID));
```

I've tried a couple different things. I'm not sure why I thought this would work.

```
var ids = new HashSet<int>(myObject.Select(p => p.ID).Where(p => p != null));
```

and this which seemed like it should work.

```
var ids = new HashSet<int>(myObject.Select(p => (p == null) ? 0 : p.ID));
```

Finally this worked but it seems like there's got to be a better way.

```
var ids = new HashSet<int>(myObject!= null ? myObject.Select(p => p.ID) : new int[] {0});
```

Anyone have a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Now, your answer can be cleaned up just a bit:

```
var ids = new HashSet<int>(myObject?.Select(p => p.ID) ?? new [] {0});
```

Answer (score 1):

If myObject is null, your code translates to

```
var ids = new HashSet<int>(null.Select(p => p.ID));
```

You cannot use the Select extension method off of null.

Your alternative

```
var ids = new HashSet<int>(myObject!= null ? myObject.Select(p => p.ID) : new int[] {0});
```

is the most compact form I'm aware of to meet your requirements, though certainly you could hide that complexity in a method or an extension method if you like.

Comment: Do you think I'm sacrificing readability for compactness? I look at it and it makes sense but will someone else see that line of code and find it overly convoluted?